# send data to a node view without losing form data

Tags: node.js, express, redirect

I have the following view

```
router.post('/save',
[
  body('name').not().isEmpty().withMessage('name empty'),
  body('surname').not().isEmpty().withMessage('surname empty'),
  body('email').not().isEmpty().withMessage('email empty'),
  body('password').not().isEmpty().withMessage('password empty')
],
(req, res)=>{
  let errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    req.session.msgs = errors.array({ onlyFirstError: true });
    return res.redirect('/signup');
  }
   //save form data......
});
```

Ok, so I get some data from a login form and I want to go back to that login form , with some error messages.

It all works fine except that the form is empty after the redirection. If I put everything except, say password, I go back to the form and is empty , so I have to fill it again from scratch along. I want to go back and the name, surname and email be still there and re-enter just the password.

Is there a way to go back and whatever fields where not empty, still have their values?

Thanks

[node 8.11.1 + express 4.16.3 + express-validator]

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `node 8.x` you can use one for core modules of `nodejs` which is

[**`querystring`**](https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html). And using this, you can send the data in query string. The idea is to send the received parameters back to redirected view like

```
  const params= querystring.stringify({
      "name": body('name'),
      "surname": body('surname'),
      "email": body('email')
       ...
  });
  res.redirect('/signup?' + params);
```

Now these parameters will be available on your view and you can access them in `singup` view and fill the related fields

Comment: Nice thinking, but I guess its pretty weird to put form values on a query string. I mean, I never saw this as a practice anywhere. I guess the right thing to do is check the form with javascript in front-end before sending, and re-check on server side, that is mandatory anyway. So front-end javascript will check and not let the form submit, keeping its values. Then the server side will never do a redirect if the values are right. This will happen very rarely , if for some reason the front-end javascript check are somehow bypassed. --but normally no server side redirect will occur

Comment: yes you're 100% right. But there are situations where you may need to send params when redirecting. You already got what you need (how you mentioned in above comment). Ignore this answer